# How to pass model class object as argument props to another component

Tags: react-tsx

I am trying to pass model class object called UserModel as props from App component and Home component to Register component.When it pass from App component,the UserModel's should be passed with IsMember property with 'false' . If it pass from Home component , IsMember property should be passed with 'true'. But in Register component  UserModel.IsMember always coming with IsMember = false. How can I pass IsMember  propert with the value 'true' from Home component .

```
UserModel.ts
class UserModel{
 IsMember: boolean
 constructor(){
 this.IsMember=false;
 }
}
export default UserModel


Register.tsx
const Register = props: {user:UserModel}) => {
console.log(props.user.IsMember)
}

App.tsx
const user = new UserModel();
<Route path ="register" element ={Register user={user}/>

Home.tsx
const handleRegisterClick = () => {
  const user = new UserModel();
  user.IsMember = true;
  Navigate('/register', { state: { user: user } });
};
```